# Is there a secure way to share sessions in the same server with different sub domains?

Tags: php, cookies, session-management

I'm studing a case that I have a RESTful backend (php-based) and a hybrid HTML+JS+PHP front-end in different subdomains:

```
backend.example.com  <-- A RESTful API to provide some XHR requests.
*.example.com  <--  Any other domains on the same server that use the same PHP Session.
```

A way to  initiate a persistent session in PHP without the placement of a session cookie is creating your own session id and setting it using session_id() function.

Disabling session cookie storage in fact doesn't allow me to maintain session across sub domains. So I implemented a Session Manager Class, to control all my classes' lifecycle, and to allow sharing the session across subdomains:

```
   public static function sessionStart($name, $limit, $trusttoken){

            (...)

    $userip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $userbrowseragent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

    $id = md5($userip . $salt .  $userbrowseragent  . $sessionname); //Creating unique ID

    session_id($id);                
    session_start();

            (...)
   }
```

## Is it a secure way to share sessions in the same server but using diferent subdomains?

#### Note

- The Sessions will be read only in server side(PHP files)
- I don't care about trusting XHR requests.
- I'm avoiding exposing session id in requests.
- It's not possible to use SSL.

Comment: It's not possible to use SSL??? I would not expect much security without that...

Comment: `I'm avoiding exposing session id in requests.` How do you maintain session state without transmitting session id? Is the persistent session backend, frontend or both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An application should rely upon the platform's session handler. Rolling your own session handler is dangerous.

A cookie can be scoped to the parent domain and used by every sub-domain. In PHP this can be done with [session_set_cookie_params()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php) to change the scope the domain to `*.example.com`.  Then use `session_start()` normally.

XSS on any subdomain may compromise the session id.  Make sure to enable the `Secure` and `HTTPOnly` cookie flags.  This will ensure that HTTPS will be used with the session id for all requests, and limit the impact of XSS.

Additionally,  **generating a session id using the following method is insecure**:

```
$id = md5($userip . $salt .  $userbrowseragent  . $sessionname);
```

Never attempt to roll your own random number generator. A session id must be a [cryptographic nonce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce) generated with a cryptographically secure pseudo-random number generator (CSPRNG).  The hash function `md5` must never be used in a security context,  it has been broken since 2005.  Even if a secure hash function were used, the attacker will knows the `$userip`, `$userbrowseragent` and the `$sessionname`,  which means they could bruteforce the `$salt` value offline.

Comment: Hello, sorry for my delay to check this awnser... saw many examples using .example.com, what is the difference between both?
Thanks

Comment: `*.example.com` is a scope that encompasses all subdomains of `example.com`